# how to prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{m}k!k=(m+1)!-1$ without induction?

Tags: summation

how to prove that $$\sum_{k=1}^{m}k!k=(m+1)!-1$$ without induction ?

my only try is to put $k!=\Gamma(k+1)$ then use geometric series with some steps but I got complicated integral

If any one can solve it using my way or similar way using calculus technique

Comment: First of all, all you can ever do with this sort of problem is hide the induction. You can't even define the sum "without induction."

Comment: I personally want a counting argument.

Comment: @nayrb See my answer, then.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{m}k!k \\
\sum_{k=1}^{m}k!(k+1-1) \\
\sum_{k=1}^{m}k!(k+1)-k! \\
\sum_{k=1}^{m}(k+1)!-k! \\
= 2!-1!+3!-2!+4!-3!+\cdots + (m+1)!-m! \\
=(m+1)!-1
$$

Comment: oh my god but I need 4 minutes more

Comment: Telescopy *is* induction in disguise. But as Thomas Andrews pointed, it is impossible to prove this without induction. This argument is kind of nice, though. +1.

Comment: @chubakueno I agree and thanks.

Answer (score 6):

There is a combinatorial approach.

The number $(m+1)!-1$ counts the number of non-identity permutations of $\{1,2,\dots,m+1\}$.

On the other hand $k\cdot k!$ counts the number of such permutations that fix all elements greater than $k+1$ but not $k+1$.